# st_intersect count result for each row

Tags: postgresql, count, postgis

I have two polygon tables a freeform, and a grid in postgres. I would like to count all the grid polygons what they intersect with the freeform polygons for each freeform polygons. I can do for one freeform:

```
select count (*) from (select a.* from durs_area b, grid a where b.job_reference = '1571754' and ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.the_geom)) as zulu;
```

Is there any way to create a query what will add the number of intersecting grid polygons for each freeform polygons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a join (rather than an unnecessary sub-query), and an aggregate.

```
SELECT ff.job_reference, count (g.*)
FROM durs_area ff
JOIN grid g ON ST_Intersects(g.geom, ff.the_geom)
GROUP BY ff.job_reference, ff.the_geom;
```

Comment: I changed the a.job_reference to ff.job_reference and worked perfectly. Thanks